# Going from Illustrator to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I've been having some trouble lately trying to create some simple images when going from AI to PS.

I'm initially starting out with this apple logo vector that I want to convert to a white color in photoshop, clipping away the rest of the image, leaving only the logo.

These are the steps that I'm taking that seem to lead me to a jagged looking picture:

1. Copy and paste the AI file into PS as a smart object.
2. Resize
3. Rasterize the layer
4. Use rectangle marque tool to select everything but the logo and cut it out of the picture.
5. Use the paint bucket to color it white.
6. All done. But it looks jaggedy. Am I doing the right steps for this? Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processes makes little sense.

Vector artwork has no background by default. If there is a background, it must be comprised of other objects you can simply click and delete in Illustrator.

Taking a vector piece into Photoshop, then rasterizing it to remove the background is a *very, very, very, very* poor workflow.

Here's what you do....

Search for the Apple Logo on [Brandsoftheworld.com](http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/search/logo/apple) and download it. (You'll have to sign up, but there's no cost and they don't spam you.)

Open the downloaded file and use that. They won't have any backgrounds.

Comment: I don't have a background, I was just deleting other stuff that came with that vector file (such as text). Also, since you seem knowledgeable on this topic, if I take an image from AI to PS should I simply copy and paste it as a smart object?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it. Smart Objects pasted from AI to PS have some issues (no gradient dithering, potential antialiasing problems). If you want a solid colour or single gradient, I'd paste as a shape layer.

Comment: @EGHDK - Open the file in Illustrator and use the Selection Tool (Black arrow) or Direct Selection Tool (White arrow) to click and delete anything you don't want. Then copy what you do want in Illustrator and paste it into Photoshop. What method you choose to paste (Shape Layer, Smart Object, Paths, or Pixels, depends on where you want to go with the art.